# Python MySQLdb setting a user defined variable

Tags: python, mysql-python

Here's my code:

```
if NNlib.neuro(SB, UZ) == 1:
    koncept = 'zid'
else:
    koncept = 'prazan prostor'

sql = "SET @koncept='%s';" % koncept
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

So basically what it does is NNlib.neuro returns either a 1 for 'zid' ('wall' in English) and 0 for 'prazan prostor' ('empty space'). This part works just fine, I'm having a problem with setting a user defined variable in SQL with the second part of the code.

For example, when I execute the code for koncept = 'zid', I should get that @koncept is 'zid' but I'm getting a NULL value.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Actually I cannot set any user-defined variable. This code doesn't work:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="istrazivac")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SET @test = 5")
conn.commit()
```

When I do a SELECT @test in mysql I get a NULL value. But when I set it in mysql> it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since the user-defined variables in MySQL are bound by the session, as in they are erased once the session is over, it's only logical that selecting the variable in mysql terminal would return a NULL value. The python script starts one session and the mysql from terminal another and thus the user-defined values are different.

Hope this helps someone with the same trouble.